# how to increase the value of a progress bar by clicking a button in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

in WPF, i have a Progress bar, and i want to increase the value of that progress bar after clicking a button.
i tried creating an instance of the timer class when the button is clicked and increment the value of the 
progress bar inside the timer's timer callback method , but it doesn't work and throws the invalid operation exception .
here's the code i have:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnProgress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 100);
}

private void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    progressBar.Value += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to update a UI control from a non-UI thread. Easy to fix by changing the TimerCallback method as shown below.

```
private void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value += 2, DispatcherPriority.Background));
}
```